# SED: append after first match

Tags: sed

Is there a way to append a text after first match only with `sed`? I've got something like this but text is inserted every second line:

```
sed -e '0,/priority/a\exclude = php*' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

File

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo 
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
priority=3

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
priority=3

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
priority=3
```

**UPDATE:**

Desired output - `exclude = php*` should be only in the first repo ([epel]):

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo 
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
priority=3
exclude = php*
...
```

Comment: Where do you want the new line to be? The command you show clearly adds the line after every line in the specified range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say:

```
sed '/^priority/{s/.*/&\nexclude = php*/;:a;n;ba}' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Comment: nice usage of label, clever solution! simpler than mine. +1

Comment: Could you please explain what these options do `;:a;n;ba` - it looks like this command works without them?

Comment: @HTF No without the part you've highlighted, the line would be appended to all lines beginning with `priority`.  See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands).

Comment: anadis-mbp:tmp anadi$ sed '/^gpgkey/{s/.*/&\nexclude = php*/;:a;n;ba}' yum1.repo 
sed: 1: "/^gpgkey/{s/.*/&\nexclu ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: I get this error when trying the sed command. I am trying to add line under base section after gpgkey=file:/// .... which happens to be last line of all sections in the rep definition file

Comment: @AnadiMisra Are you using BSD sed?  This would work with GNU sed.

Comment: I copied this command with modification to run in a CentOS machine, here is the error when i try to execute this command, sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @AnadiMisra I'd suggest you to ask a question instead with your sample input, expected output, what you attempted, any other information that you feel would be relevant.

Comment: question added, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932381/see-add-exclude-postgres-under-base-and-updates-section, would be good to know where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution in addition to `sed`

```
awk '/^priority/ && !f {$0=$0 RS "nexclude = php*";f=1}1' file
```

If search is found and `f=0`, then add text and set `f=1`. This prevents adding text after all `priority`.

Comment: OP mentioned **only with sed**.

Comment: I know, but its always nice to variation, it may be that OP did not know it was possible with `awk`. Plus `awk` code may be more easy to understand/read compare to the codes in `sed`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed  '/priority/{x;/1/{x;b};s/^/1/;x;s/.*/&\nexclude = php*/}' file
```

the above line may work for you.