# sed: add exclude=postgres* under base and updates section

Tags: shell, sed, centos6

/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
```

I want to add

exclude = postgres* after gpgkey line under the [base] section using sed, the expression

```
sed '/^gpgkey/{s/.*/&\nexclude = postgres*/;:a;n;ba}' /etc/yum.repos.d/CetnOS-Base.repo
```

does not change the file, I get error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
```

running this command, am I missing a switch or the expression needs correction?

Comment: No error here on `GNU sed`, even with `--posix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using BSD sed.  You can say:

```
sed '/\[base\]/,/gpgkey=/{/gpgkey=/s/$/\'$'\n''exclude = postgres*/;}' filename
```

to append the line `exclude = postgres*` after `gpgkey=...` in the `[base]` section.

EDIT: Explanation:

- `/\[base\]/,/gpgkey=/` matches an addresses range, i.e. lines starting from the one containing `[base]` upto the one containing `gpgkey=`
- `{/gpgkey=/s/$/\'$'\n''exclude = postgres*/;}` is a group of commands that is executed only for the addresses matched above

Breaking down `/gpgkey=/s/$/\'$'\n''exclude = postgres*/`:

- This performs the mentioned substitution `s/$/\'$'\n''exclude = postgres*/` on lines that match `gpgkey=`.
- The above substitution matches `$`, i.e. the end of line.
- The replacement is a newline followed by `exclude = postgres*/`
- `$'\n'` is ANSI-C quoting syntax for producing a newline.  Since you didn't seem to be using GNU sed, hence this was required.  Else `\n` would suffice, i.e. it could have been written as `/gpgkey=/s/$/\nexclude = postgres*/`

Comment: sed '/\\[base\\]/,/gpgkey=/{/gpgkey=/s/$/\\'$'\\n''exclude = postgres*/;}' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, executes without error, but no change occurs in the file. I am using it inside exec resource of puppet manifest

Comment: @AnadiMisra You need to pass the `-i` option in order to make the changes to the file in-place.  `sed -i ...`

Comment: ah! thanks, can you also explain what the second \'$' is for? from what I can figure out we are saying append after you find gpgkey = any string with exclude = postgres*, something like that :-)

Comment: @AnadiMisra Added explanation above!

Answer (score 0):

Try this inline sed with `}` in separate `-e` block:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^gpgkey/{s/.*/&\nexclude = postgres*/;:a;n;ba;' -e '}' /etc/yum.repos.d/CetnOS-Base.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed '/\(\[base\]\|\[updates\]\)/,/gpgkey/{/gpgkey/s/.*/&\nexclude=postgres*/}' /etc/yum.repos.d/CetnOS-Base.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed '/\[base\]/,/gpgkey/{/gpgkey/s/.*/&\nexclude = postgres*/}' /etc/yum.repos.d/CetnOS-Base.repo
```